# Unable to replace an empty string in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a varchar(100) column that has some empty values.
When I try to replace the empty strings with a value, nothing happens. I cannot figure out why.
I am sure the value in the cells is not null.
I can reproduce with a temporary table and some sample data.

The below SQL should return a result set in which the [ReplacedTextCol] always has a value, but even when using replace, I cannot replace the empty string:

```
create table #tempt
(
    col1 varchar(100)
)

insert into #tempt(col1) 
values('')
,('')
,('some value')

select replace(col1, '','replaced') as ReplacedTextCol,* 
from #tempt
```

The result of the above query is shown below:

[image]

Table, DB & server uses the collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Appreciate any pointer as to where I'm going wrong.

Comment: If you think about it, it's quite logical. An empty string has *no* characters. How many 0-length substrings are in `abcd`? What you ask should either match *all* characters as if it were a wildcard, or none

Comment: Use `case when` or `IIF()` instead of REPLACE. You're looking for an exact match after all, not find an empty string inside another string. Eg use `IIF(col1='','replaced',col1)`

Answer (score 3):

[REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) doesn't work with empty strings:

> *string_pattern*
>
> Is the substring to be found. string_pattern can be of
> a character or binary data type. string_pattern cannot be an empty
> string (''), and must not exceed the maximum number of bytes that fits
> on a page.

Use simple UPDATE:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET SomeColumn = 'replaced'
WHERE SomeColumn  = '';
```

Or SELECT:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SomeColumn = '' THEN 'replaced' ELSE SomeColumn END
FROM YourTable
WHERE SomeColumn  = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE is used to replace one substring with another, you want COALESCE or a SELECT CASE construct to replace empty values, try

```
select CASE WHEN COALESCE(col1,'') = '' THEN 'replaced' ELSE col1 END as ReplacedTextCol,* 
from #tempt
```

Comment: That's not what COALESCE is for, or what your own answer uses. This answer uses `CASE WHEN` to return a different value if a field contains an empty string. COALESCE replaces a null value with a specific value, which isn't needed here

Comment: COALESCE replaces a value when empty is represented as NULL, if you might have some NULL and some as an empty string (which COALESCE won't touch) you need both COALESCE and CASE, the COALESCE converts NULL to EMPTY, and the CASE checks for EMPTY and converts to the final value. Depending on the source of data, mixed NULL and EMPTY might be a big problem and this works for all.